# PHP - Using a function outside the file it has been created in

Tags: php, function

I have 3 php files. The first (connexion.php) one contains a function I use to create a new PDO connexion:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

function connexion($host, $user, $pass, $db){
    $db_host = $host;  
    $db_user = $user;  
    $db_password = $pass;  
    $db_database = $db;               
    return $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_password);
}

?>
```

The second file (my_function.php) contains a function that contains only one function that connects to a db and then is echoing some information.

```
    <?php
    include(connexion.php);
    function my_first_function(){
        try{
           $connexion = connexion('localhost', 'user', 'user', 'mydb');
           $connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           //some code that echoes information
        }
        catch(...){...}
    }
    ?>
```

My problem is when I try to include that last file into my third php script in order to be abble to use the function. The script is not even launching. I just have 'internal error'. If I remove the include(my_function.php) my file is loaded properly. I don't get it. Hope someone can help me understand. Thanks in advance. Cheers. Marc. Here below the third file:

```
<?php
include('connexion.php');
include('my_function.php');

//some code
my_first_function();
?>
```

Comment: Turn the debug output on, this has nothing to do with your function.

Comment: Do you have the two files in the same directory? Are you using the exact case for the file you are trying to include?

Comment: Also, get in the habit of dropping your last '?>'. While it's annoying, PHP does wacky stuff if there are invisible characters after your close-php tag.

Comment: Where does it say 'Internal error'? How does it say it? What program says it? Does it say anything more than that?

Comment: Hello all. Thks for trying to help. I just edited my post to make it more clear. By the way all the file are not in the same folder but the paths are good. I checked and double checked...

Comment: Just got the following error "Cannot redeclare connexion()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `include('connexion.php');` in the third file as it will also be included already automatically when you do `include('my_function.php');`

As it contains a function declaration, that will lead to an error because that function has already been declared.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks. Do you know if there is a way I can check if the file is already included. Something like if(is_included(file.php))?

Comment: @Marc Use `include_once` to get around this.  You could check if it was included by calling `function_exists` on a function defined in that file.  Or you could use get_included_files() to get a list of files already included.

Comment: @Marc I agree, include_once is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

"Internal error" is not a PHP thing, you may want to check your .htaccess or other apache settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to include the file more than once, you will get errors because PHP won't allow you to redeclare a function with the same name. To get around that, use:

```
include_once("my_include_file.php");
```

Comment: Hello ANthony. Thks for trying to help. The problem seems to be more linked to my connexion function as I just got this fatal error : "Cannot redeclare connexion()"...

Comment: If that is the case, you need to use `include_once`

Answer (score 0):

You are either not providing the relative path to the include file or your include file has an error inside it. To test this, try the following code..

```
if( file_exists('the_file_where_the_function_is.php') )
{
    echo "Found the file";
} else {
    echo "File not found";
}
```

If it finds the file, then you most likely have a syntax error in the included file. Also I am guessing you are using IE and getting an "Internal Server Error" ??? If so go into your preferences for IE and turn off friendly error messages to see the actual PHP error.

Comment: Hello pogeybait. The path is corrected. i checked and rechecked. Otherwise I am using the chrome debugger and it is only saying 'internal server error'...